# "Welcome to Nginx!" - Docker-Compose, using uWSGI, Flask, nginx

Tags: docker, nginx

**My Problem:**

[image: Welcome to Nginx! splash]

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and a docker-compose based solution with two Docker images, **one to handle Python/uWSGI** and **one for my NGINX reverse proxy**. No matter what I change, it always seems like WSGI is unable to detect my default application. Whenever I run `docker-compose up`, and navigate to `localhost:5000` I get the above default splash.

The complete program appears to work on our CentOS 7 machines. However, when I try to execute it on my Ubuntu test machine, I can only get the "Welcome to NGINX!" page.

**Directory Structure:**

```
 /app
  - app.conf
  - app.ini
  - app.py
  - docker-compose.py
  - Dockerfile-flask
  - Dockerfile-nginx
  - requirements.txt
  /templates
```

*(All code snippets have been simplified to help isolate the problem)*

Here is an example of my docker traceback:

**clocker_flask_1**

```
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from app.ini
current working directory: /app
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 0.0.0.0:5000 fd 3
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***
*** Operational MODE: preforking+threaded ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 1 seconds on interpreter 0x558072010e70 pid: 1 (default app)
```

**clocker_nginx_1**

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
```

**Here is my docker-compose.yaml:**

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  
  flask:
    image: webapp-flask
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-flask
    volumes:
      - "./:/app:z"
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
    environment:
      - "EXTERNAL_IP=${EXTERNAL_IP}"

  nginx:
    image: webapp-nginx
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-nginx
    ports:
      - 5000:80
    depends_on:
      - flask
```

**Dockerfile-flask:**

```
FROM python:3
ENV APP /app
RUN mkdir $APP
WORKDIR $APP
EXPOSE 5000
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD [ "uwsgi", "--ini", "app.ini" ]
```

**Dockerfile-nginx**

```
FROM nginx:latest
EXPOSE 80
COPY app.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

**app.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    location / { try_files $uri @app; }
    location @app {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass flask:5000;
    }
}
```

**app.py**

```
# Home bit
@application.route('/')
@application.route('/home', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():
    return render_template(
        'index.html',
        er = er
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

**app.ini**

```
[uwsgi]
protocol = uwsgi
module = app
callable = application
master = true
processes = 2
threads = 2
socket = 0.0.0.0:5000
vacuum = true   
die-on-term = true
max-requests = 1000
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The nginx image comes with a main configuration file, `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, which loads every conf file in the `conf.d` folder -- including your nemesis in this case, a stock `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`. It reads as follows (trimmed a bit for concision):

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;

  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
  }
}
```

So, your `app.conf` and this configuration are both active. The reason why this default one wins, though, is because of the `server_name` directive that it has (and yours lacks) -- when you're hitting `localhost:5000`, nginx matches based on the hostname and sends your request there.

To fix this easily, you can just remove that file in your Dockerfile-nginx:

```
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Comment: I went ahead and added this to my Dockerfile-nginx like so:
   /   
EXPOSE 80 / 
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf / 
COPY app.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
   /   
I also SSH'ed into my clocker_nginx_1 Docker image and installed nano, and sure enough, it had been deleted. However, I'm still getting the "Welcome to Nginx!" splash when I try to navigate a web browser to "localhost:5000". Any other suggestions as to what could be happening?

Comment: @EthanHill well, one thing I notice locally is that hitting `localhost/index.html` directly still loads the welcome page, since `try_files` will find that file before it tries to go to your Flask app. You might try also removing the static index files, or change the root on your app.conf to a different folder to avoid the conflict. The output of your nginx access logs would also be helpful to diagnose. I copied your nginx container to reproduce and resolve the problem, but I may have missed something.

Comment: This suggestion did not resolve my issue. However, it is possible that it could solve someone else's similar issue, so I am marked it as solved.

Comment: @EthanHill were you able to resolve your issue in a different way? One other thought would be to just mount your app.conf to overwrite /etc/nginx/nginx.conf itself, to avoid dealing with the overriding the default configuration that provides.

Comment: I threw out my entire boilerplate and replaced it with the tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-docker image -- it seemed to be the simplest solution given the time constaints.